# Spring SAML wso2

Tags: java, spring, wso2, saml, wso2-identity-server

Im doing the implementation of saml authentication using the Spring saml sample and a basic configuration for saml in wso2 identity server

So far I'm getting this error after the login when the wso2 server response to my application.

And I have no idea what to look out.

> org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: **Error determining metadata contracts**
>       at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:91)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:211)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:166)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:87)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1636)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:564)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:578)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1111)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:498)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1045)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:199)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:98)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:461)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:284)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:244)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:534)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:607)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:536)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
>   Caused by: org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException: **Metadata for issuer *something* wasn't found**
>       at org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl.retrieveMessage(SAMLProcessorImpl.java:108)
>       at org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl.retrieveMessage(SAMLProcessorImpl.java:172)
>       at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:77)
>       ... 36 more

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue as described above.  This is 2 years old however I do not want to ask the same question.  I'm using WSO2 IS 5.2.  I researched the source code and found the error occurs in the SAMLProcessorImpl class.  Specifically here: if (samlContext.getPeerEntityMetadata() == null) {
            throw new MetadataProviderException("Metadata for issuer " + samlContext.getInboundMessageIssuer() + " wasn't found");  Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by making sure the "Identity Provider Entity Id" matches the "IdP metadata entityID".  The "Identity Provider Entity Id" setup is found in the WSO2 IS (ver 5.2.0) management console under: Identity Providers/Resident Identity Provider/SAML2 Web SSO Configuration.

The "IdP metadata entityID" is an attribute of the EntityDescriptor tag (per the [spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-metadata-2.0-os.pdf)).  I manually created the WSO2 IdP metadata.  Here is my IdP metadata:

```
<EntityDescriptor entityID="localhost_wso2" validUntil="2023-09-23T06:57:15.396Z" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" >
<IDPSSODescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
<KeyDescriptor use="signing">
 <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
   <ds:X509Data>
    <ds:X509Certificate>...</ds:X509Certificate>
   </ds:X509Data>
 </ds:KeyInfo>
</KeyDescriptor>
<SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://localhost:9443/samlsso" ResponseLocation="https://localhost:9443/samlsso"/>
<SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://localhost:9443/samlsso"/>
<SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://localhost:9443/samlsso"/>
</IDPSSODescriptor>
</EntityDescriptor>
```

I referenced the above IdP metadata in my Spring-Saml config like so:

```
<bean id="metadata" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
<constructor-arg>
  <list>
    <!-- Example of classpath metadata with Extended Metadata -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
      <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.ResourceBackedMetadataProvider">
          <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="java.util.Timer"/>
          </constructor-arg>
          <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.opensaml.util.resource.ClasspathResource">
              <constructor-arg value="/metadata/wso2idp_metadata.xml"/>
            </bean>
          </constructor-arg>
          <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
        </bean>
      </constructor-arg>
      <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
        </bean>
      </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
  </list>
</constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think spring SAML sample is looking for IDP metadata. It may assume that WSO2 Identity Server supports for SAML meta data profile.  But as i know, [this](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-metadata-2.0-os.pdf) profile is still not supported by the Identity Server. However, there may be a place where you can manually configure the IDP meta data in the sample. Therefore please check for it. Because normally it is not required support this profile by all IDPs there must be some option to ignore it and manually do it.

Also,  you can find the IDP meta data of Identity Server that has been created manually from [this] blog

Comment: Yes I'm using the metadata that I found in a blog. but I'm not hardcoding the issuer mentioned above, I'm trying to figure out out to ignore it or set a valid one. Thank you.